# Pros and Cons of of importing modules in a single line in Python

Tags: python, import, module

I was curious about using:

```
import pandas as pd, random, numpy as np
```

instead of:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np
```

PyCharm gives me warning "PEP 8: E401 multiple imports on one line" and suggest optimization which separates all modules to its own import line.

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports Probably just to try and make your code clearer

Comment: Note that separate lines per import is much friendlier for version-control/diffs.

Comment: Beyond `E401` itself you might easily hit `E501` (line too long) if you would want to put `import`ing more than few modules in one line.

Answer (score 4):

By importing on separate lines, you will be following [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidance on [imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

> Imports should usually be on separate lines

Answer (score 0):

There are no pros or cons, only correct and wrong. See [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)

Answer (score 0):

PEP8 is a style guide for python, while it doesn't have a computational advantage it makes your code more readable and therefore easier to maintain.

If you are interested, you can read more about it here [pep](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)